# Missing info.plist key ( but i have the key )

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

[image: missing info key]

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? I have xcode version 9.4.1

I have already tried cleaning :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to add like as below: check your value of that key

```
 key: Privacy - Contacts Usage Description 


Value: Allow Contact Access
```

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of research I found the cause of this was moving a new info.plist into my project. After adding this Contacts Usage Description to the origional info.plist , along with everything else I needed for my case it worked. 
**lesson learned**
when moving files to a new xcode project the project doesn't reference them automatically